# E-mail terminology NO AT HARVEST

Tags: email

I wanted to know what means "NO AT HARVEST" in a email terminology like:

```
             asdasdasd DOT asdasd NO AT HARVEST gmail DOT com
```

I think its the @ symbol but im not sure.

Thanks in Advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the @ symbol, also known as the [at sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign).

The term *"no at harvest"* would refer to circumventing programs that scrape web pages harvesting email addresses by looking for the @ character.